# Issue to redirect to new page using javascript from aspx page which is inherited from master page.x

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a master page `MainMaster.master`.
Also have one aspx page name as `AllDetails.aspx` which is inherited from 
`MainMaster.Master` page.

I have button on `AllDetails.aspx`, as like below-

```
<button class="button" type="submit"  onclick="redirect(' + Id + ');">View           Details</button>
```

On click above button i am calling below function `redirect`

```
function redirect(id) 
{ 
    jQuery(xml).find('HK').each(function (i, v)
    {
        window.location.href = "../View/AllDetails.aspx?Uid=" + id;
     }); 
}
```

As per the above function i am trying to redirect to `AllDetails.aspx` page.
But unfortunately its not redirecting. I checked this function in firbug and tried to debug line by line its working. If i remove the breakpoint and try directly its only refreshing current page.

Please guide.

Comment: why u r trying to redirect in jquery.each loop

Comment: have you tried window.location instead of window.location.href? and I guess no need of looping here

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript/21396837#21396837

Comment: In loop  i am chceking below condition. I had not given in question to decrese code complexity.
jQuery(xml).find('HK').each(function (i, v)
    {
           if (parseInt(jQuery(v).find('PR').attr('Id')) ==  parseInt(id)) {
           window.location.href = "../View/AllDetails.aspx?Uid=" + id;
}
           }); 


Also tried window.location -No luck :(

Comment: Hi All Any solution for this?